# How to append data to a TS object?

Tags: typescript

Basically I have an API that returns an object, and I want to add a field to it.  Simple, but I can't figure out how to make TS happy.  It either wants my extra field when I'm creating the object, or it wants it to be optional (which it isn't, it just doesn't exist for one line of code):

```
function createThing() {
    return {x: 42};
}

const myThing: ReturnType<typeof createThing> & {y: number} = createThing(); // complains that y doesn't exist
myThing.y = 43;
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQFQBYxgDmAFAJSIDeAUInYulCCkpQB4BciALAEwC+Abmr9q1CAgDOURAFsAnvkJEuAJTRMWOeQAc0AHii60cYMnRZcBYgD5EAMiryuYELIBGaFP0QBec5jYSsTkwgrBRAB08n48AMyCQA)

Comment: `{...createThing(), y: 43}` should be good enough

Comment: If you declare it as though it also has `y` then you need to provide the `y` in the initial assignment as well otherwise `createThing` type doesn't match `myThing`

Comment: The spread doesn't actually work, my fault for over-simplifying :)  The actual return value from the function has a prototype attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your requirement, but I think you are looking for [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
function createThing() {
    return {x: 42};
}

const myThing = Object.assign(createThing(), {y: 3});
console.log(myThing.x); // 42
console.log(myThing.y); // 3
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC4DMBXMYAFwEtwACYVWZM2AFQAsKwBzLagb12qDq9MkVRg+ADwBc1ACwAmAL54l+UJDLUAtgE82HTtQC81APIAjAFaxy8ZBAgVOYdHQZMDXLABo+u2QBmJRxcDSg4eGgQbj0vTnhJHGoAehT5BTDwCIRo2P12LnhdZLTqQNw4woTdE2oARgU8cJhcmPQqw2LS9Mb8XBSAKkGBQepkABMJiGoAB1QQWdhUMlragHcKMlZqADdkaCJYPgABaA4Aa2pdJWoyED5zsCuQazVqQZTCEnIqCUmJgBNAA8zGosEkTDA02orxs5AAfOg4bJmH4AtQwERtBZlpg+AIhCIxBJLPCyPZHM5XHC-LwbqE1FlNHdqgAlWAQIjQLSmdyMFjVLDNbJabaGDlcnkAdS2rEBdQBgPQ4q4ku5ZD8ClCLUieRV7M5Gtl20BiR6GWZOSi7VVnHVMrlZpK2FS6UyuCAA)